# Showing HTML contents in Managed Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, security, locker-service

We have developed a Managed Grid component where users can dynamically pass column definition and data which will be rendered as SLDS table. We support datatypes such as `Text,Date,DateTime..` so on.

We are considering supporting `RichTextArea` type based on some of our client's feedback. Since we will need to show the HTML content in a column, Our question is:

Do we need to ***sanitize*** the HTML content that is passed to the component? If Yes, Are there any Salesforce/Locker Service approved libraries available out to strip out problematic tags like ***script***,.. and return proper content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the markup is stored in your org as an entity field, it should have already been sanitized before storing by our api layer. 
When it comes to the UI, any attempt to set innerHTML on a node and such will be sanitized by LockerService. We use DOMPurify for sanitizing the markup.

Just a suggestion, have you thought about using the standard lightning components that support RTE? Like lightning:inputRichText for example https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputRichText.htm
You could use the lightning:outputField to display the data and it dynamically chooses the lightning:outputXX type based on your field type.

Comment: Source of the RichText data can be from SF/3rd party API provider as well. We'll be doing innerHTML way rather than using lightning components at the moment. Since Locker does the sanitization work for us, so we are fine right?

Comment: innerHTML is sanitized. You are good to go. https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/6623c2a1e5ddfbd7000624c5d873a14051256f22/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureElement.js#L342

Comment: Getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createNodeIterator' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` using DOMPurify, any suggestions?

Comment: @Aequitas Thanks for the detailed error message. It looks like locker service is not handling the arguments sent to createNodeIterator() correctly. I have logged an issue for us to fix that W-5284583

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa Any updates on this fix? I am getting same issue when passing in a string without any special characters using DOMPurify.sanitize method

Comment: in regards to the error `'createNodeIterator' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`, I'm assuming the issue is caused by the fact that the Locker Service uses DOMPurify and if you try to add your own DOMPurify, it won't work because the Locker Service will sanitize the DOM making it a non-Node element causing the error, or in other words (DOMPurify sanitizes itself, self-destroying itself). What I would like to know is, can we access the Locker Service `sanitize` function directly from any component?